# Multiple tkinter inputs to dict value

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have to insert multiple tkinter inputs to dict in python

See my code snippet below

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(selection) :
    dict = {'aaa' : selection,
            'bbb': selection)
    print (dict)

root = tk.Tk()

opt = tk.StringVar()
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, opt, 'a', 'b', 'c', command=callback)

opt1 = tk.StringVar ()
menu1 = tk.OptionMenu (root, opt1, 'a', 'b', 'c', command=callback)

menu.pack()
menu1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Depends on input as output l have dictionary with same values

`{'aaa': 'a', 'bbb': 'a'}`

Or

`{'aaa': 'b', 'bbb': 'b'}`

Or

`{'aaa': 'c', 'bbb': 'c'}`

However I want to be able to set different values

Eg

`{'aaa': 'c', 'bbb': 'a'}`

Comment: `selection` is obviously going to be the same thing both times you use it in that function - and you have no idea *which* OptionMenu it came from, since you've used the same function as the callback for both of them.  You need to explicitly use `opt.get()` and `opt1.get()` to retrieve the two specific selections.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the names of the tkinter variables, you can ignore the value passed to the callback and directly the the values by calling `get()` on the individual variables.

```
def callback(selection) :
    dict = {
        'aaa' : opt.get(),
        'bbb': opt1.get()
    }
    print (dict)
```

Comment: Is there way to change all values at one?

Comment: Sorry I am writing from phone. I am receiving {'aaa': 'b', 'bbb': ''} an then {'aaa': 'b', 'bbb': 'c'}. Can I receive second output without first?

Comment: @Zalman: if you have the callback associated with each optionmenu, then the callback will be called when each optionmenu is used to pick a value. If you only want it to be called for the second optionmenu, but add the callback to the first one. Or, add a "submit" button to your UI.